# Instalo Primevue con NuxtJs pero no funciona

Tags: javascript, nodejs, vue.js, npm, nuxt

He instalado un proyecto de nuxt usando como framework de UI "primevue",

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues de ejecutar npm run dev, parece que no muestra los componentes correctamente. no se si es por el CSS o que directamente no carga los componentes ya se muestran correctamente.

**Mi configuracion Nuxt.config.js**

```
export default {
  // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
  ssr: false,

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'socialApp',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
      'primeflex/primeflex.css'
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [],


  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase-v2/#/setup
    'primevue/nuxt',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
  ],

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    // Workaround to avoid enforcing hard-coded localhost:3000: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/308
    baseURL: '/',
  },

  // PWA module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
  pwa: {
    manifest: {
      lang: 'en'
    }
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    // https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/issues/844
    transpile: ['primevue'],
  }
}
```

Alguien podria decirme por que no me funciona? SI en teria he seleccionado el ui de Primevue y llamo a un componente basico y no funciona.

```
 <Fieldset legend="Header" :toggleable="true">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </Fieldset>
```

Muestra esto....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El proyecto se muestra en localhost, pero los componentes estan mal.